# What is the real-world purpose of an optional 1:1 relationship?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I know that one-to-one relationships can be used to split data into multiple tables for performance or security and that it is used to create a is-a-relationsship.

But aside from that things, what is the real-world prupose of an optional one-to-one relationship, expecially one where both sites are optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows records to exist on either side of the relationship independently, with ties between records that happen to be related.  If you have a real life question about this you should add the details.

Comment: appropriate for modelling a marriage?